# Handling spaces in a directory in bash sh

Tags: bash, directory, sh, space, cp

I have this line `cp $(find "$directory" -type f | grep -iE '\.(c|cc|cpp|cxx)$') ~/src` which searches a given directory (in this case, `$directory` is /home) and copies all file with the extensions of .c, .cc, .cpp and .cxx into the src folder, but I get an error of cp:cannot stat `directory`: No such file or directory.

I thought putting the directory in quotes would prevent that. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error is from the command `cp`, so quoting `$directory`, while generally a good idea, won't help you solve this error.

Your construct will fail with file/directory names that contain spaces, cases where grep turns out with zero matches, and probably other cases I can't think of right now.

Some better solutions:

- Use `find`'s name matching instead of `grep`, and use `-exec` with it:

  ```
  find "$directory" -type f \( -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.cxx' \) -exec cp '{}' ~/src ';'

  find "$directory" -type f -regextype posix-egrep -iregex '.*\.(c|cc|cpp|cxx)$' -exec cp '{}' ~/src ';'
  ```
- Use `xargs` with `\0` separators instead of `\n`:

  ```
  find "$directory" -type f -print0 | grep -z -iE '\.(c|cc|cpp|cxx)$' | xargs -0 -I{} cp "{}" ~/src
  ```
- If your file structure is flat (no subdirectories), just use `cp`:

  ```
  cd "$directory"; cp *.c *.cc *.cpp *.cxx ~/src
  ```

Comment: Nice! In the first example, you should add parentheses around the `-name .. -o -name ..` part, since `-o` has lower precedence than the implicit `-a` in front of `-exec`. In the second example, you could additionally remove the line feed problem using `find -print0` and `grep -z`. For the third, you could `shopt -s globstar nullglob;` and then use `**/*.{c,cc,cpp,cxx}` to go recursively and/or get rid of the errors if there happens to be no .cxx files, only .cpp files.

Comment: Your 2nd example would be better like this: `find "$directory" -type f -iregex '.*\.(c|cc|cpp|cxx)$' -print0 | xargs -0 ...`